# UISplitViewController - stack of UIViews

Tags: iphone, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a problem in adapting my iPhone App to Universal.
In my iPhone App, I have a tabBarController, with 5 tabs, each one with a tableView.
I need now to adapt it to iPad, so I'm implementing the following:
. A UISpliViewController, in which the rootViewController (left pane) is a tableView, to display in detailViewController (on the right side), each controller, corresponding to the tarBarController on the iPhone.
So, my problem is where do I assign the controllers to the splitView? In AppDelegate?
If I assign them in viewDidLoad on rootViewController, it don't work.

Anyone can help me? I'm stuck.

Thanks,

iChat: rui.lopes@me.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the AppDelegate's:
    `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

method.

EDIT: Also see this SO post. Had bookmarked this when I started out.

[UISplitViewController programmtically without nib/xib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757489/uisplitviewcontroller-programmtically-without-nib-xib-thank-you)

Comment: the problem is that i have it built in xib, so i don't need to alloc and init the splitViewController.
Can we talk in iChat or Skype? I'm going crazy today... :(

Comment: Go to developer documentation on Xcode and search for "MultipleDetailViews" and open that project and study it. Let me know if that clears up your nib/xib based uisplitviewcontroller issues.

Comment: hi, i've studied it, but my problem is: i need do init all 5 viewControllers at startup, and then show them when the user taps each row on the rootViewController.
How can I do it?
In the - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOption
Or just after I add the splitViewController to the window?
Can we speek on iChat or Skype?

Answer (score 1):

create your splitview controller either in the xib or programmatically, then set the viewcontrollers

```
  splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:leftViewController, rightViewController, nil];
```

in either method

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application or 
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done it.
I've added 5 ViewControllers to the AppDelegate, and the problem is solved.

Thanks,

Rui