# Creating a Master Detail Navigation Controller programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

I followed [this excellent tutorial here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S_J_r8AKw0k) on how to set up a Master Detail Navigation Controller with no problems.

However I now want to create a Master Detail Navigation Controller programmatically, without using the Interface Builder. Ive tried to retype the code I entered in the above tutorial, but it seems I am missing certain things to get it to work.

Ive Googled around and found [this tutorial here](http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/navigation-based-project-doing-it.html), but this one doesnt give me quite what I was expecting.

Can anyone point me to a tutorial which will create a Master Detail Navigation Controller programmatically, or provide me with the code needed to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a good enough [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757489/uisplitviewcontroller-programmtically-without-nib-xib) :)